# Where should jpos.xml be located for JavaPos Tomcat app.?

Tags: javapos

I am trying to add in a new driver to our system running under Tomcat.  The vendor has provided a JavaPos driver, my question is where to put the jpos.xml file so Tomcat can find it?

I tried putting it in tomcat\common\classes but still get a JPOSException
"Service does not exist in loaded JCL registry" when I try to open it.  Help!

---

Yes correct, JavaPOS.  I'm integrating JavaPos into an existing client side Tomcat app., and would like to know the correct place (in the expanded war file) to put jpos.xml and also jpos.properties.

Thanks a lot, fred.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know if this would help a five year old question!

```
/*
 * If you want to place the jpos.xml file elsewhere on your local file
 * system then uncomment the following line and specify the full path to
 * jpos.xml.
 *
 * If you want to place the jpos.xml file on a webserver for access over the
 * internet then uncomment the second System.setProperty line below and
 * specify the full URL to jpos.xml.
 */
System.setProperty( JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "jpos.xml" );
//System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_URL_PROP_NAME, "http://some-where-remote.com/jpos.xml");

System.setProperty("jpos.loader.serviceManagerClass", "jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager");
System.setProperty("jpos.util.tracing.TurnOnNamedTracers", "JposServiceLoader,SimpleEntryRegistry,SimpleRegPopulator,XercesRegPopulator");
System.setProperty("jpos.util.tracing.TurnOnAllNamedTracers", "ON");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about JavaPOS, not jPOS?

Comment: This is not an answer.  Move it to be a comment on the original question, please.